# Pandas GroupBy object is not 'serializable' by Plot.ly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to create a boxplot using Plotly and I get an error when attempting to use a Pandas DataFrame that's been grouped. Some initial digging produced this chunk of code to convert Pandas to Plotly interface:

```
def df_to_iplot(df):

'''
Coverting a Pandas Data Frame to Plotly interface
'''
x = df.index.values
lines={}
for key in df:
    lines[key]={}
    lines[key]["x"]=x
    lines[key]["y"]=df[key].values
    lines[key]["name"]=key

    #Appending all lines
lines_plotly=[lines[key] for key in df]
return lines_plotly
```

Are there alternatives to this method of converting DataFrame's to a Plotly-compatible series? The above code is for line graphs, but I'd like to iterate over my dimensions to produce a boxplot for each group in my DataFrame. Here is the error message I'm getting:

"TypeError: pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object  is not JSON serializable"

Here is an example from the Plotly website: https://plot.ly/python/box-plots

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

py.sign_in("xxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx")

import numpy as np
y0 = np.random.randn(50)
y1 = np.random.randn(50)+1

trace0 = Box(
    y=y0
)
trace1 = Box(
    y=y1
)
data = Data([trace0, trace1])

unique_url = py.plot(data, filename = 'basic-box-plot')
```

Comment: When you group a DataFrame, the result is not a DataFrame.  It's a GroupBy object, as your error message suggests.  Can you give an example of the data format and what it is that you want to plot?

Comment: right, that makes sense. My data are school performance scores grouped by county (where each county has several schools with corresponding grades). I'd like to plot a boxplot for each county (representing the min/med/max, etc. of the scores in that county).

Comment: I don't really know anything about plotly.  Can you give a description of the format you need the result in?  Does it have to be a dict or what?

Comment: Instead of putting code in the comments, please edit your post.  Can you provide a link to the example you mean?  The only plotly boxplot example I find by googling doesn't make any mention of a Series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want something like this:

```
data = Data([Box(y=v.values) for k, v in g])
```

(where `g` is your grouped object).  Then you can use `py.plot` on that.

Like I said in the comments, I know nothing about plotly; I'm just going based off your example.  We'll see if anyone who knows more about plotly replies.  Failing that, it would be helpful if you could explain in your question what format you want the data in (i.e., figure out what format plotly wants).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond. If I follow your code right, the k and v iterators represent the dimensions of my grouped DataFrame? So essentially 'for county, school in DataFrame' is how that would read?

Comment: @Wipa: I believe so, but I can't be sure without seeing your data.  I suggest you take a look at [the groupby documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to understand how you can use the GroupBy object.  That will help you understand what's going on in my example, as well as how to use the GroupBy object in the future.